# How to customize Excel TableStyle at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I'm trying to build a custom `TableStyle` in an Excel COM Add-in project. I'm not getting any errors, but the `TableStyle` seems to simply ignore many (but not all) of my style commands.

I am able to set the `...Interior.Color` property just fine. But I can't get `Borders`, `Font.Bold` nor `Font.Color` to work. When I see my table style in excel, these are just set to their defaults.

The code I'm using to do this is an extension method for the `TableStyle` Object. In practice, it is being passed a newly created `TableStyle`, created with the `Excel.Workbook.TableStyles.Add` method. It also uses a `ITableStyle` object that simply contains some color values. I've included an example of color values being provided in code comments.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void StyleAs(this Excel.TableStyle tableStyle, ITableStyle style)
    {
        var styleElements = tableStyle.TableStyleElements;

        //WholeTable ************
        var wholeTable = styleElements[Excel.XlTableStyleElementType.xlWholeTable];
        //Background Color
        wholeTable.Interior.Color = style.BodyColor; //(this is passed the value 0XF3FFFF; It works)
        //Font Color
        wholeTable.Font.Color = style.BodyFontColor; //(this is passed the value 0 and it doesn't work. excel shows color is being set by the ColorIndex = xlAutomatic)

        //Headers ***************
        var headers = styleElements[Excel.XlTableStyleElementType.xlHeaderRow];
        //Border
        headers.Borders.Item[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous; //(does not seem to work)
        headers.Borders.Item[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom].Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlMedium; //(does not seem to work)
        //Font
        headers.Font.Bold = true; //(this does not work)
        headers.Font.Color = style.HeaderFontColor; //(passed the value 0XFFFFFF; this does not work)
        //Fill
        headers.Interior.Color = style.HeaderColor; //(passed value 0X1159C6; it works!)

        tableStyle.ShowAsAvailableTableStyle = true;
    }
```

Comment: you can record macro in Excel of setting the style manually, and inspect the produced VBA code after https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b

Comment: @Slai - in fact I did do this - however it ended up not being helpful as it appears to be doing the same sort of thing that I'm doing. The only difference was that it was setting the value for every property. I tried adding code to set the value of properties to their default values for those values that I didn't actually want to change, but alas, no luck :-(

Comment: okay this is weird... but apparently changing the Interior.Color property is resetting the other properties. If I change the order in which I set property values (setting Interior.Color first), everything works.